# Changing the name of a domain internally

Tags: dns

I have given my client a domain like www.xyz.com/test.

Now for some reason I want to change it to www.xyz.com/testing but I want that client will continue to type www.xyz.com/test.

How can I do it?

Comment: What platform? What server? Are you talking about web?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup a HTTP 301/302 redirect from `/test` to `/testing`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're on an Apache server you should be able to use an [htaccess](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=htaccess&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) file to route the URL to the actual location on your server. There's a couple of ways of creating 301/302 redirects, such as a plain RewriteRule that routes all calls to "xyz.com/testing/..." to the actual location on the server, "xyz.com/test/...".

Good luck! =)